# remote Multiple invocations using Powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, remote-server

I appreciate you taking the time to read this.

My issue is as follows: I'm trying to create a program that uses powershell to do the following:

1. Take a table generated outside of powershell
2. Loop calls to a powershell script with the parameters from the table
3. The powershell script calls a special type of .cmd file and then runs commands on it that are located in a different shared location.

Now my problem is with the 3rd point.

I'm currently using the following to call my script (and the arguements are just hard coded to get it working, they'll be generated by the calls from step 2 later on):

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {invoke-command -file \\sharedlocation\test5.ps1 -computername server1121 -argumentlist 7058,Jason}
```

The inside of test5.ps1 is currently:

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string] $Var1, 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string] $Var2
)

$CommandsPath = "\\sharedlocation\testcommands.cmd"
$path = "C:\"+$Var1+"\TOOLS\"+$Var2+"launchtool.cmd"
$scriptPath = [scriptblock]::Create($path)
$out | invoke-command {PARAM($MyArg) $scriptPath } -ArgumentList $CommandsPath
```

I've also tried using

```
$CommandsPath = "\\sharedlocation\testcommands.cmd"
$path = "C:\"+$Var1+"\TOOLS\"+$Var2+"\launchtool.cmd & " + $CommandsPath
$scriptPath = [scriptblock]::Create($path)
$out | invoke-command {$scriptPath }
```

I've also tried to call with hardcoded testcommands instead of them being in a file.

Now my problem is in both cases, it DOES run launchtool.cmd, but it doesn't pass the testcommands.cmd file.

However when on the machine i run

```
 C:\7058\TOOLS\Jason\launchtool.cmd & \\sharedlocation\testcommands.cmd
```

It works fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're issue seems to have more to do with getting cmd and powershell to do the same thing, rather than "multiple remote invocations"

Comment: What is `$out` and why are you piping it to `Invoke-Command`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, invoke-expression "cmd.exe /c C:\7058\TOOLS\Jason\launchtool.cmd & \sharedlocation\testcommands.cmd"

cmd.exe /c is my best way to ensure consistency between cmd and powershell

Comment: It actually works when i hard code it, the problem is when i try to use generated paths. I'll keep trying with cmd.exe /c 


I've modified it so it looks like the following:


`$CommandsPath = " \\sharedlocation\testcommands.cmd"
    $path = "cmd.exe /c C:\"+$Var1+"\TOOLS\"+$Var2+"launchtool.cmd    '&'" + $CommandsPath
   Invoke-Expression $path`

This actually works fine when i run it on the server itself, but remotely launched (using an account that has proper permissions) , it still runs launchtool.cmd but gives access denied for the second part.

Comment: You might need cmd /c "your-command here" - meaning quote the command

Answer (score 0):

Is the UNC Path accessible from powershell? Copy the testcommands.cmd to a local path and try if it works!

```
$CommandsPath = "\\sharedlocation\testcommands.cmd"
if(Test-Path $CommandsPath)
{
   $path = "C:\"+$Var1+"\TOOLS\"+$Var2+"\launchtool.cmd & " + $CommandsPath
   $scriptPath = [scriptblock]::Create($path)
   $out | invoke-command {$scriptPath } 
}
```

Comment: It is accessible both from the shared path and when copied locally. I tried following Mrwaim's suggestion below, and now i'm getting launchtool.cmd running, but access denied on the testcommands.cmd section even though the entire thing works when i run it from powershell on the server itself, and the account i'm using has full access to all machines (confirmed)

Comment: You may need to check the execution policy in the remote machine and set it to remotesigned. Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force